# How to center the first and the last cell of a horizontal UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I'm trying to center the first and the last cell of a **horizontal collection view**.

The only approach i found until now was adding extra cells at the begin and the end of my `UICollectionView`. This method was totally a bad idea for obvious reasons but I didn't find a better way to do it for now. And since, with the iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6+, the layout of my view is totally broken... (facepalm)
To illustrate my need I need to display something like this :

```
|        x x x x x|  where the first x represent my first cell

and

|x x x x x        |  where the last x represent my last cell
```

I think using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass is the proper way to do that with `contentInset` stuff but I'm a total newbie with these components. 
Any links or suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting here for future reference, as I've been working with same problem, and found a solution. 
Tested in Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) with Swift 3

The UICollectionViewDelegate has the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets`

To center the first and last cell in the collection view, your calculate the inset by:

```
let inset: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width * 0.5 - cellSize.width * 0.5
```

After this, you simply return the new `UIEdgeInsetMake(0, inset, 0, inset)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let inset: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width * 0.5 - cellSize.width * 0.5
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, inset, 0, inset)
}
```

-------***Edit***-------

In this case I store the cell size as a hard coded value, and set it by using the delegate `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

Comment: if scrolling is enabled, how can we center scrolling item?

Answer (score 0):

Easy handle for your different sections.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, collectionView.frame.size.width/2, 0, collectionView.frame.size.width/2);
}
```